# How to imitate in Perl the behaviour of wget or curl

Tags: perl, activemq-classic, wget, nagios

I am a newbie in Perl and in ActiveMQ.

I have downloaded this [Perl nagios program](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/scripts/activemq_watch) to check the ActiveMQ queues. The problem is the program exist in the main Perl line:

```
my $page = get "http://admin:admin\@$address:$port/admin/xml/queues.jsp" or die "Cannot get XML file: $!\n";;
```

I substituted that line with this other lines to check the return code:

```
 my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 $ua->timeout(10);
 $ua->env_proxy;

 my $page = $ua->get("http://admin:admin\@$address:$port/admin/xml/queues.jsp");

 if ($page->is_success) {
     print $page->decoded_content;  # or whatever
 }
 else {
     die $page->status_line;
 }
```

Now, it reports:

```
401 Unauthorized
```

But `wget` is still able to download the page:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8161... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to 127.0.0.1:8161.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2430 (2.4K) [text/xml]
Saving to: `queues.jsp'
```

How can I config the `UserAgent` to make the `get` call imitate the `wget` behaviour?

Do you know another script/program to monitor de ActiveMQ queues?

Is there any way to get the queues values in plain text? Then I would write down my own bash script.

**update 1**

As @mob requested, here it is the output of `wget --debug`

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.

--2017-09-06 19:27:15--  http://admin:*password*@127.0.0.1:8161/admin/xml/queues.jsp
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8161... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000002586c10 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x0000000002586c10.

---request begin---
GET /admin/xml/queues.jsp HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: 127.0.0.1:8161
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="ActiveMQRealm"
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1293
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Jetty(7.6.9.v20130131)

---response end---
401 Unauthorized
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Skipping 1293 bytes of body: [<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /admin/xml/queues.jsp. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>


</body>
</html>
] done.
Reusing existing connection to 127.0.0.1:8161.
Reusing fd 3.

---request begin---
GET /admin/xml/queues.jsp HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: 127.0.0.1:8161
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=o7kaw1kbzcy91dozx82c8dq2j;Path=/admin
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 2430
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Jetty(7.6.9.v20130131)

---response end---
200 OK

Stored cookie 127.0.0.1 8161 /admin <session> <insecure> [expiry none] JSESSIONID o7kaw1kbzcy91dozx82c8dq2j
Length: 2430 (2.4K) [text/xml]
Saving to: `queues.jsp'

100%[================================================================================>] 2,430  --.-K/s in 0s

2017-09-06 19:27:15 (395 MB/s) - `queues.jsp' saved [2430/2430]
```

The only difference in the `---request begin---` sections of both attempts is

```
 Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

found only in the second try.

Comment: The `\@` escape also isn't expanded in single quotes.

Comment: @simbabque I wrongly posted my first attempt of my code. Then I realized and changed into double quotes.

Comment: Run wget with `--debug` flag to see how it recovers from the initial 401 response.

Comment: @Schwern, Thanks, I modified my post. But I this post shows a port number (8161) which is not the actual one of my ActiveMQ server.

Comment: @Jdamian Don't even post test passwords. They're all too often reused as real passwords. If not, they give an insight into how you make your passwords. For example, this one was too short, and too simple. The patterns say its hand made and created to be remembered. They tell me you're not using a password generator nor a password manager, or you're not using it judiciously, so your passwords will be weak. I suggest you get into the habit of using a password manager for everything.

Comment: @Schewrn, I did not generate that password because I'm not the ActiveMQ admin. I'm only trying to monitor the queues. In fact, I'm not allowed to change anything from the ActiveMQ server configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LWP::UserAgent does not parse the `username:password` part of the URL. I suspect this is to discourage the insecure practice of putting the username:password in the URL where it will then be easily stolen from programs and in server logs.

You can override `get_basic_credentials` to pull the username and password out of the URL. This doesn't solve the security problem.

Or you can call `authorization_basic` on an `HTTP::Request` object to set the username and password for this particular request.

```
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
  $req->authorization_basic($user, $password);
  my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

Or you can call `credentials` on the UserAgent to set up passwords for various host/port combinations rather than for just one request. This is like storing your passwords in the browser, where `$ua` is the browser.

```
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  $ua->credentials("$host:$port", $realm, $user, $password);
  my $req = $ua->get($url);
```

Or you can switch to the less featureful but better designed [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) or the slightly more featureful [HTTP::Tiny::UA](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny::UA). It will parse and use the `username:password` part of the URL.

```
  use HTTP::Tiny;
  my $ua = HTTP::Tiny->new;
  my $res = $ua->get($url);
```